# Why didDiscover peripheral not called?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I want to scan all the nearby Bluetooth devices.
I don't know what I am doing wrong in my code so my didDiscover peripheral method is not called.
Below is my my tried code.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
var peripherals = Array<CBPeripheral>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Initialise CoreBluetooth Central Manager
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}
}
extension HomeViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    if (central.state == .poweredOn){
        self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    }
    else {
        // do something like alert the user that ble is not on
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Bluetooth is off", message: "Please turn on your bluetooth", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    print(peripheral)

}
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you have any BLE devices nearby?  Core Bluetooth won't discover legacy Bluetooth devices like speakers or headsets.  Does the LightBlue app from the App Store discover any peripherals? Do you get the call to `didUpdateState`?

Comment: I don't have BLE devices nearby. I have my android phone and macbook near me. LightBlue app also not discover peripherals near me.Yes, I get the call to didUpdateState.

Comment: You can only discover devices that are advertising BLE GATT services.  It isn't possible for apps on iOS to discover legacy Bluetooth devices.  You could run an app on your Android phone or your Mac to advertise as a peripheral and then you will be able to discover that

Comment: You can try this https://tomsoderling.github.io/Turn-Mac-into-BLE-peripheral-device/